# Is it possible to Clear all variables (but not functions)?

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, clear

I have written a Mathematica script in which I define functions and variables.  Here is a ***vastly*** simplified example:

```
myFunA[int_Integer] := int + 1
myFunB[int_Integer] := int * 2
myFunC[int_Integer] := int - 3

myVarA = 1;
myVarB = 2;
myVarC = 3;
```

(In my actual script, the function and variable names vary; they do *not* follow the form `myFunX`, `myVarX`, etc.)

I would like to `Clear` (or otherwise delete) *all* of the *variables* (`myVarA`, `myVarB`, `myVarC`) but **not** the functions (`myFunA`, `myFunB`, `myFunC`).  Is this possible (without explicitly `Clear`ing each of the many variables, since my actual script defines several dozen variables)?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Automatic way based on `Names`

Here is a simple modification of the [recent answer of @R.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10970/how-to-clear-all-variables-except-one/10975#10975), which is based on the definiton of a variable as a symbol which has an `OwnValue` defined:

```
Clear @@ 
   Select[
      Names["Global`*"], 
      ToExpression[#, StandardForm, 
         Function[sym, OwnValues[sym] =!= {}, HoldAll]
      ] &
   ]
```

If your code is in some context other than `` Global` `` (which is what I'd recommend), you can put that context in place of `` Global` `` above.

#### Automation based on custom assignment operator

As an alternative, and IMO more systematic way, you may define a custom assignment operator which you'd use when defining a variable:

```
ClearAll[defVar, $variables, clearVars];

$variables = Hold[];

SetAttributes[defVar, HoldAll];
defVar[def : ((Set | SetDelayed)[lhs_Symbol, rhs_])] :=
  With[{result = def},
    $variables = Append[$variables, Unevaluated[lhs]];
    result];

clearVars[] := $variables /. Hold[vars__] :> Clear[vars];
```

Now, you use this as

```
myFunA[int_Integer] := int + 1
myFunB[int_Integer] := int*2
myFunC[int_Integer] := int - 3

defVar[myVarA = 1];
defVar[myVarB = 2];
defVar[myVarC = 3];
```

And then,

```
clearVars[]
```

#### A digression: evaluation leak in `AppendTo`

Interestingly, in the line `$variables = Append[$variables, Unevaluated[lhs]]`, you can not use `AppendTo` instead, at least not in the form one would expect it to work. The reason is rather subtle: `AppendTo` seems to be implemented in the top-level code, but more importantly, it leaks evaluation:

```
vars = vars1 = Hold[];
a=1;
AppendTo[vars,Unevaluated[a]];
AppendTo[vars1,Unevaluated@Unevaluated[a]];
{vars,vars1}

(* {Hold[1],Hold[a]} *)
```

You see that an extra layer of `Unevaluated` is necessary to counter the evaluation leak.
I would think this is a wrong behavior for `AppendTo`, but can not state with definiteness that this is a bug.

#### Remarks

Which way to choose depends on the situation. The first method is fully automatic and will work best if you keep all your work in a specific context distinct from `` Global` ``. The second way requires more discipline but works regardless of the contexts you are using.

Comment: Using `OwnValues` as suggested has one possible drawback: it would select, among other entities, a symbol defined to be a pure function.

Comment: @murray That the symbol contains a value that happens to be a pure function does not make that symbol be not a variable. Rather, it confirms that Mathematica is a functional language (or, rather, an emulation, but often we don't have to make a difference), where functions are values, as well as other types. Only my opinion, of course. And I agree with you that this creates an ambiguity in the question, but then the question itself has to be better formulated to cover this case.

Comment: @murray Actually, I really agree with you that the type of automation provided by the first method may be too dangerous since it takes a rather cavalier approach towards variable clearing. This was the whole reason why I described the second one, where you have a choice to not wrap `defVar` around an assignment if you don't want to treat the symbol there as a variable.